# exclude a particular directory and exclude a list of files

Tags: java

The code I have works for copying all direcotries and files but not sure on how to exclude a
 particular directory under music and exclude a list of files

1) For example, I have Music folder and lots of subdirectories. Want to exclude spanish 
   subdirectory and copy everything under Music folder to destination

```
The second condition which I wanted to check is
```

2) Under Music folder I wanted to exclude all text files and copy

```
`    private void copyFiles(File src, File tgt) throws IOException
                   {

                     if(src.isDirectory())
                   {
         try{
                if(!tgt.exists()) tgt.mkdirs();
                String[] filePaths = src.list();
                for(String filePath : filePaths)
               {
                File srcFile = new File(src, filePath);
                File destFile = new File(tgt, filePath);
                copyFiles(srcFile, destFile);
               }
          }
        catch(Exception ie)
              {
                ie.printStackTrace();
              }
         }
    else
             {
                try
                     {
                        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
                        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tgt));
                        long fileBytes = src.length();
                        long soFar = 0;
                        int Byte;
             while((Byte = bis.read()) != -1)
                       {
                         bos.write(Byte);

                       }
                          bis.close();
                          bos.close();

                      }
           catch(Exception excep)
                            {
                              excep.printStackTrace();
                              bos.flush();
                              bis.close();
                              bos.close();

                            }`
```

Comment: You could take a look at [File.listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) which takes a [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) object. There's also already a [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) method, which alleviates the need to do it yourself, especially byte by byte which can be __very__ slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) takes a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) which can be used to determine if certain files should be included or not in the listing returne by `File#listFiles`...

This is okay if you know in advance what you to to include/exclude.  If you want to make the process more dynamic, you could pass a list of `FileFilter`s to the `copy` method and then use  a special `FileFilter` to iterate over them...

```
private void copyFiles(File src, File tgt, FileFilter... filters) {
    /*...*/
    File[] filePaths = src.listFiles(new GroupedFileFiler(filters));
    /*...*/
}

public class GroupedFileFilter implements FileFilter {

    private FileFilter[] filters;

    public GroupedFileFilter(FileFilter... filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        boolean include = true;
        if (filters != null && filters.length > 0) {
            for (FileFilter filter : filters) {
                include = filter.accept(pathname);
                if (!include) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return include;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that always return true? You really don't even need that boolean variable anyway if you just return false in the if statement and true at the end.

Comment: @sbat - It will only return `true` if all the filters return `true`, but if you don't supply any filters, it will return `true`.  I'm old school.  I believe in one entry point and one exit for all my methods.  It's too easy to miss a return statement hidden in compound `if` and `loop` code - but that's just me...